# Spring Batch or BIRT framework

Tags: java, spring, report, birt, cobol

I am very new to this. Kindly advise me.Basically, I want to convert the COBOL code to Java and generate reports using Spring Batch or BIRT framework. Can you please advice how to start off with this or any underlying architecture of how it works or any references will be helpful.

Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Spring Batch is a batch framework as the name suggests. BIRT is the tooling/runtime library for report generation. You are comparing apples and oranges. Both can work together to generate reports in batch though.

Need the below info if any architectural suggestions have to be made

1. Are the reports always generated in
   batch mode or there is a on-demand
   requirement
2. Why do you think you should be using
   spring-batch and BIRT?
3. A simple flow on how reports
       are handled now Which application
       server etc

Comment: thanks for the reply..ya I want to use both depending on loc..can you please explain in detail how exactly the above scenario works with either or the frameworks (i mean how to get the reports) in an architectural way..I am an absolute beginner in this and it is very essential for me to learn how exactly in works..please help me out..or can you suggest any resources..

Comment: Pangea..as far as my knowledge there is no need to use batch processing now. It's one of the specifications we have to use either spring batch or birt based on LOC. Right now I think the reports are generated using COBOL in mainframes which we need to write it back in java..not sure of application server :( I am very sorry. I have very minimal requirements with me..please guide me and thanks a lot for all your time

Comment: This is going to take a lot of time for me..as much as I hate to signup for this...i also want to help...so 1) what is LOC? 2) Who created the specification that says you have to use spring batch? spring batch is something similar to JCL in mainframe world. 3) In what format are the reports being generated now? 4) What is the reason for rewriting it in Java? 5) Who are the target audience for your reports 7) How are the reports being delivered to the user now? 6) Share your specification